# bad option: '-Yliteral-types' SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

I have below scala `build.sbt` file.

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.8"

val ccompileOptions = Seq(
  "-unchecked",
  "-deprecation",
  "-language:_",
  "-encoding", "UTF-8",
  "-Ypartial-unification",
  "-Xfatal-warnings",
  "-Yliteral-types",
  "-language:higherKinds"
)

scalacOptions ++= ccompileOptions

enablePlugins(TutPlugin)

tutTargetDirectory := baseDirectory.value

resolvers += Resolver.bintrayRepo("ovotech", "maven")

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "is.cir" %% "ciris-cats",
  "is.cir" %% "ciris-cats-effect",
  "is.cir" %% "ciris-core",
  "is.cir" %% "ciris-enumeratum",
  "is.cir" %% "ciris-refined"
).map(_ % "0.12.1")

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.http4s" %% "http4s-dsl",
  "org.http4s" %% "http4s-blaze-server"
).map(_ % "0.19.0")

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.ovoenergy" %% "ciris-kubernetes" % "0.5" ,
  "org.typelevel" %% "kittens" % "1.2.0",
  "eu.timepit" %% "refined-cats" % "0.9.3"
)
```

The project can be found at github [here](https://github.com/rajcspsg/ciris-example/tree/intermediate). Just need to update scalaVersion to `2.12.8` and comment out this [section](https://github.com/rajcspsg/ciris-example/blob/intermediate/build.sbt#L1-L6).

If I remove `scalaVersion := "2.12.8"` and add the below then the compilation successful.

```
inThisBuild {
  Seq(
    scalaOrganization := "org.typelevel",
    scalaVersion := "2.12.4-bin-typelevel-4"
  )
}
```

when I googled, looks like `-Yliteral-types` option is removed from scala according to this [issue](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/10710).

But I have created a project with [scala version 2.12.8](https://github.com/rajcspsg/scala_with_cats/blob/master/build.sbt#L5) with that `-Yliteral-types` flag enabled [here](https://github.com/rajcspsg/scala_with_cats/blob/master/project/CompileOptions.scala#L9) and it is working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you will have to use either Dotty or the Typelevel compiler to access this feature as you discovered. While the docs of [SIP-23](https://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/42.type.html) don't make this point explicit, the links you've provided above combined with the docs do.

Comment: then how does this project https://github.com/rajcspsg/scala_with_cats which doesn't ue either dotty or typelevel compiler allows `-Yliteral-types` https://github.com/rajcspsg/scala_with_cats/blob/master/project/CompileOptions.scala#L9?

Comment: @RajkumarNatarajan it doesn't compile. Do `sbt "; project ch_1_intro; compile"` and you'll get `bad option: '-Yliteral-types'`.

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ IDEA with Scala plugin shows message:

> For literal types support use Scala 2.13 or Typelevel Scala with
>   `-Yliteral-types` compiler flag.

[image]